# Android Facebook Push Campaign Beta not working

Tags: android, facebook, push-notification, facebook-android-sdk, beta

[Image Link -> Facebook Push Campaign(Beta) Error Message while I was scheduling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFyzo.png)

Hi all! I was trying the Facebook Push Campaign Service, during the test in the settings page the Push and In-app notification worked perfectly. But when I tried in the Push Campaign it was not working. I've faced with this messae "***An unexpected error has occured, please try again later***". That is why I couldn't schedule push campaign...if anyone faced this error, how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @liquide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/push-campaigns/android I used this code on facebook-push-sdk document..and then I've received test push from facebook. and made a segment. but I couldn't make push campaign with segment. There's unexpected error..when I tried to confirm push campaign.